.Net 8 API Json Serialization Failing: JsonTypeInfo error
I am making a call to an API I am developing and I get an error:

JsonTypeInfo metadata for type 'BFNG_Library.Models.App_admin' was not provided by TypeInfoResolver of type '[]'.

This is the class. I added the JsonSerializable attribute:
public record App_admin
{
    public string? Role { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
}

[JsonSerializable(typeof(App_admin))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(List<App_admin>))]
internal partial class AppJsonSerializerContext2 : JsonSerializerContext
{
}

This is the API endpoint in my controller:
public class AdminController : Controller
{
     [Route("api/admin/create")]
     public string PostCreate([FromBody] App_admin Admin)
     {
         // Implementation removed
     }
}

Not sure if it makes a difference, but the class (App_admin) is in a different project (BFNG_Library) which I have added as a project dependency on the actual project (BFNG_Program).
I even changed the API signature to require a string instead of App_admin viz:
public string PostCreate([FromBody] string Admin)

When I do this, the error changes to

JsonTypeInfo metadata for type 'System.String' was not provided by TypeInfoResolver of type '[]'

I find it quite confusing as string is a base type. Is there some missing config I have not included?
Environment: Windows, .NET 8
Any help will be appreciated

you don't need anything special: yout model looks fine, so the first PostCreate handler. Get rid of everything else, and it'll work.

Thanks for your response Mario. I don't quite understand what you mean by "Get rid of everything else". Can you explain a more

You don't need the AppJsonSerializerContext2 class. The App_admin model is fully deserializable without any other external help.

@Mario: That's how I began (without the AppJsonSerializerContext2 class), but I got the error and that led to me adding those. Seems to be a requirement in .net 8 (it's my first time on .net 8). I have never had to do that in previous .net versions

I don't see anything strange in the code. I also made several NET 8 web apps, but they work without any special stuff. Could you share the code or at least a minimal app in order to reproduce the problem? I guess there's something else making you that error.

Thanks @Mario, I took a cue from your last response, and recreated the entire project. I guessed there was something not quite right in my original setup. While recreating it, I realized I had chosen Core Web API (native AOT) and not just Core Web API as project type. Their config and requirements are different I imagine. Must be something I didn't do in the AOT config. Anyway, in the recreated project I chose the right project type (Core Web API), now everything works,

aaahh! yeah, likely that's the problem. I never made an AOT app, but I've read that there are several fundamental differences. Keep stick to the non-AOT way and everything should be easier.
